# Scale docker container with ENV settings

Tags: docker, docker-compose

If I have a simple counting program: given a starting number, the program will output 10 numbers from the starting number with increment of 1.

I want to have 0 to 49 as output (order is not a hard requirement). Can I use docker to do something like scale to 5 containers, but setting some ENV as the starting point of each container? Assuming I’m fine with multiple containers will not guarantee the order.

For example: container 1 will start with 0, container 2 will start with 10...container 5 will start at 40. The output may be [0, 9], [40, 49], [30, 39], [10, 19], [20, 29].

Comment: of course it's possible, what's the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly achieve this using the `-e` argument with the docker run command. The sample below shows how to launch containers with an environment variable `0-49` and uses the alpine image for demonstration purposes:

```
for i in {0..49}
do
    docker run -it -e "IDX_ENV=$i" alpine:latest env
done
```

Note the output will just print the environment for each invocation:

```
...
IDX_ENV=0
HOME=/root
...
```

Each container will, of course, exit after printing the environment. If you need to run something more `"real"` such as a long running process, I suggest that you run the containers in detached mode with the `-d` option and set an entrypoint that makes use of the environment passed in.

Comment: Nice, that is totally what I want! Thank you very much!!